# Como gerar um pequeno conjunto de caracteres alfanuméricos em PHP?

Tags: php

Como gerar um pequeno conjunto de caracteres em PHP, como esse `M7kL8a8z7q`?

Quero fazer um upload de documentos diversos e quero renomear os arquivos em PHP como o botão de imagens faz aqui no Stack Overflow. Se eu misturo md5, com a data e outros fica enorme.

<sup>**Não precisa seguir essa ordem de caracteres, só tem que ser randômica, não se repetir e ter 10 caracteres.**</sup>

Comment: Não poderia ser um timespan atual ou um datetime?

Comment: [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php)?

Comment: Veja se isso lhe atende: https://ideone.com/1bwioP

Answer (score 0):

Um gerador de senhas simples, você pode alterar o tamanho da senha alterando a variável `length`, e os caracteres possíveis alterando a variável `characters`. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: Arrumei, me confundi e acabei colocando uma resposta com JAVA